# How to send the buffer correctly in node.js via response.write?

Tags: node.js, node.js-buffer

I am trying to send out the binary content from a node.js server. To do this, I allocate a buffer and fill up the buffer with my content, and call `response.write()` on it. Once it returns, I reuse the buffer with the new content. However it doesn't seem to work correctly for some reasons.

Here is the server code:

```
const http = require('http');

async function sendChunk( response, outbuf )
{
    console.log( "Sending buffer: %s", outbuf );

    // Send the buffer out. If it returns false, 
    // this means the kernel buffers are full,
    // and we have to wait until they are available.
    if ( await response.write( outbuf ) === false )
    {
        await new Promise(resolve => response.once('drain', ()=>{
            resolve();
        }));
    }
}

async function sendData( response )
{
    let outbuf = Buffer.alloc( 20 );

    for ( let count = 0x45; count < 0x50; count++ )
    {
        for ( let i = 0; i < outbuf.length; i++ )
        {
            outbuf[i] = count;
        }

        await sendChunk( response, outbuf );
    }
}


function webRequestHandler( request, response )
{
    let body = [];

    request.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(err);
        return;

    });

    request.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body.push(chunk);
    });

    response.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error( "Error sending response: %s", err);
        return;
    });

    // A whole body collected - process it
    request.on('end', async () => {

        // Handle the update; can return an error message
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        await sendData( response );
        response.end();
    });
}

const webserver = http.createServer( webRequestHandler );

// Create the web service
webserver.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log("[" + process.pid + "] " + JSON.stringify(err));
    process.exit();
});

webserver.listen( { "host" : "127.0.0.1", "port" : 5252 }, () => {
    console.log( "Server running" );
});
```

When tested via `curl http://localhost:5252/` the server prints the following:

```
Sending buffer: EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
Sending buffer: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Sending buffer: GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
Sending buffer: HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
Sending buffer: IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
Sending buffer: JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
Sending buffer: KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
Sending buffer: LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL
Sending buffer: MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
Sending buffer: NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
Sending buffer: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

however the client receives something totally different:

```
> curl http://localhost:5252/
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

What's going on here? It does work if I create a new buffer in sendChunk which is a copy of outbuf. However this seem like waste of RAM, and doesn't really make sense for someone coming from C background, and there once you call `send()` on a socket, the data has been copied and you can reuse the source buffer as you wish.

Does node.js work differently? Do I need to create a dedicated buffer for response.write() which can no longer be touched once write is called, even if write has returned and I waited for the `drain` event?

Comment: I'm not sure what's your actual problem is but you can't use `await` with `response.write`. That's because it's a Stream, not a Promise (both streams and promises are merely design patterns for handling asynchronous operations but they have different APIs - Promises for example have async/await). Admittedly in this case it's a no-op (the await does nothing) but it may mislead you on what's going on

Comment: I switched response.write into callback, but it didn't change anything, so I doubt the issue is there. Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted [the bug report](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/28778), and it got closed with an important comment:

> You should be passing a callback to .write() to know when node is
>   finished with that chunk of memory instead of relying on the 'drain'
>   event.
>
> Once you make that change, you will see the output on the client that
>   you're expecting.

And indeed once the `sendChunk` function is changed as following:

```
async function sendChunk( response, outbuf )
{
    return new Promise( function( resolve, reject) {

        if ( response.write( outbuf, ()=>{ resolve(); } ) === false )
        {
            console.log( "Draining buffer" );
            response.once('drain', ()=>{
                resolve();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

so we resolve it only in the function callback, the issue goes away. The core issue here is that `response.write` is not awaitable, and returns before the callback is called.

Should have read the documentation more carefully.